AWS Lambda Function URL error (failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
I am using function url for calling lambda function. Sometime on calling AWS lambda function URL, getting error (failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED while using mobile data. I have checked this for multiple lambda functions and got the same error.
I have tried with browser, curl and postman
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 
the function is on us-east-2 (Ohio) region I tried with simple function code just return hello
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(f'event {event}')
    print(f'context {context}')
    print(f'context type {type(context)}')
    print(f"context req id {context.__dict__.get('aws_request_id')}")
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }


Please provide more details about the function. For e.g. the code and a simple use case how to reproduce the error.

I have edited the question for the code. I kept simple code just return hello to test.
The DNS error coming sometimes only that too with mobile data as I faced.

Are you really getting that error? This function is just printing lines and I do not see any reason to get any type of error. Is there any clue in cloudwatch logs?

The request is not reaching to lambda, so there is not any cloudwatch logs.

looks like mobile data problem. Nothing to do with AWS

it might be issue with mobile problem but why only with the aws function urls when other urls are getting opened?
